# How to cut polygons without lines in ArcGIS 10.4.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, arcgis-10.4

I have a road network composed of polygons and I would like to cut each polygon in way that it keeps the polygons from which the roads are made but the interior polygons are cut.
I would like to this somehow in an automate way, because doing it manually with the cut polygons tools from the edit toolbar it would take me a lot of time and I could miss some of the smaller polygons.
I have this:
[image: have.png]
and I want to cut it like this:
[image: want.png]
Lets say I have hundreds of this, all different sizes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite understanding you. You have a road network of polygons???

Comment: Can you clarify your first sentence.  From that I expect to see two sets of polygons.  I only see one (blue interior with red casings). What are the 'interior polygons from which the roads were made'?  If you want to retain the original data and have a cut version, simply duplicate the file and edit the duplicate.  Otherwise, I can't see what your problem is without clarification

Comment: Imagine a big polygon in which you make holes. The resulting layer is the  road polygon. I want to slice the roads layer like in the below example [roadsEx.png](https://s10.postimg.org/86rfrm361/roads_Ex.png). The 2 sets of polygons to which I'm referring are the roads and the empty spaces.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with a picture that shows a smaller are with what you have and what you want.

Comment: From what I understand, you have one large blue polygon (a large rectangle).  You have then drawn white polygons over the top, essentially acting as masks.  The blue bits that are still visible are your roads.  So there is still 'blue polygon' behing the white polygons.  Is this correct?  How do you want to cut them?  Always vertical? At set distances?

Comment: There are no white polygons on top. It's just the blue layer. The white that you see is the background. Momentarily, when needed, I cut them with the cut polygon tool from the edit toolbar, but the layer is being expanded everyday(more dense road network) and the task is getting tedious. I'm looking for an easier way at the moment. Direction is not important, neither the distance.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you want to keep the roads as polygons, and why you want to split them? I'm sure we can figure out a way, but I suspecting there might be a better option? What is the ultimate question the cut-road-network-polygon will answer?

Comment: So are you cutting them up because you want small polygons?  You could always create a fishnet and then cut the blue polygons by the fishnet.

Comment: The roads are for the map presented here(http://avenue.in/amaravati-plots/). The reason I want to split them is because the developer can't put masks on polygon because the API cannot support it, therefore the work around is to split the polygons and put them all one close to each other. All the reading that I did on this include a polyline or other overlapping feature to cut/split the polygon. How to cut the road network polygon in less time than doing it manually? At the moment, using the cut polygon tool, takes me around 2 hours to finish the job.

Comment: Yes, you will need an overlapping feature.  The "Create Fishnet" tool will create this overlapping feature.

Comment: @Dan_h_b the road network will look like this [smallRoadsExample.png](https://s13.postimg.org/g8a8xyw5j/small_Roads_Example.png) eventually, while some of the other white space will remain empty. I would prefer as less cuts as possible, because more cuts will increase the layers size. To be sure that fishnet cuts everything, I'll have to make the rectangles at least half the size of the smaller polygon I got to be sure that the smallest polygon is cut in 2. This will result in way too many parts.

Comment: Please keep revising your question to try and make what you are asking clear. Potential answerers will often not read comment trails and simply move onto the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution but some ideas that might help you. You will need Advanced License for some tools. Will produce weird splits when the blocks/roads are not square but maybe you are fine with that.

1- Create a opposite of your road network. For example start with a very large polygon covering all of your roads and use [Erase](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) or [Union](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm) tool with your road network and the large polygons as input to create the pink polygons in picture below.

2- Find the centroids with [Feature to point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm). Add fields StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY to them. Calculate them: StartX/Y = centroids coordinates. Add/subtract from start XY to calculate EndXY. For example use shape lenght of the pink polygons divided by 8 and add the width of the widest roads to create lines long enough to cut the roads.

3- Use [XY to line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-to-line.htm) to create cutting lines with coordinates stored in the centroids. I would probably create one going down from centroid and one going right or left for each centroid.

4- Run [Feature To Polygon](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm) with road polygon and cutting lines as input

[image]

Comment: So i started from your idea but continued differently because the road network has various sizes polygons. After the Feature to point, I used Points to Line, and with the resulted line I used the tool from [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431) called Split polygons with lines. The result wasn't what I wished for but the things got done, Thank you!